# Power BI replace (Blank) with 0 without calculated column

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report that shows Blank instead of zero

I wonder if there is any way ( through formatting or other tool) that can convert Blank to zero

without the use of new columns or measures.

[image: er]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the two blank cards usually display a number value? The problem is that when an aggregation method like SUM summarizes blank or null rows, it returns (blank). There is, for as far as I know, no way to change this default behavior when working with the built in aggregations.

Although not optimal, a solution is with a separate measure. Simply add 0 to the expression

`measure = SUM ( [Value] ) + 0`

Answer (score 1):

Include an `IF` before your measurement

```
Sum =
IF (
    SUM ( Planilha1[VALOR CONVERTIDO ] ) = BLANK ();
    0;
    SUM ( Planilha1[VALOR CONVERTIDO ] )
)
```

[image: example]